leadsheets package for songs height prop undefined
It is needed to compile the following basic code using leadsheets package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{leadsheets}%Paquete para canciones
\setleadsheets{align-chords={l}}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\definesongtitletemplate{empty}{} 
\setleadsheets{disable-measuring = true}

\begin{document}
\section*{\LARGE Cancionero 2024-I}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    
\begin{song}[remember-chords]{title={Entrada: Caminare (Em)}, music={ABV}}
\begin{verse}
  ^*{Em}Cam in^{Am}aré en pre^{C}sencia ^{B7}del Se^*{Em}ñor (Bis) \\
  ^*{Em}Am o al Señor, porque es^{D}cucha mi voz supli^{G}cante, \\
  porque ^{Em}inclina su ^{D}oído hacia ^{C}mi el ^{Am}día que lo in^{B7}voco. 
\end{verse}

\end{song}
    
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


The package leadsheets was not updated after some changes in the kernel, and latex2e-first-aid doesn't includes a patch for it (but songs is patched).
This should work (is based on similar patches for other packages that broke with the update:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\setleadsheets{align-chords={l}}

\definesongtitletemplate{empty}{} 
\setleadsheets{disable-measuring = true}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \UseName{prop_new:c}{l__leadsheets_songs_height_prop}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \section*{\LARGE Cancionero 2024-I}
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{song}[remember-chords]{title={Entrada: Caminare (Em)}, music={ABV}}
            \begin{verse}
                ^*{Em}Cam in^{Am}aré en pre^{C}sencia ^{B7}del Se^*{Em}ñor (Bis) \\
                ^*{Em}Am o al Señor, porque es^{D}cucha mi voz supli^{G}cante, \\
                porque ^{Em}inclina su ^{D}oído hacia ^{C}mi el ^{Am}día que lo in^{B7}voco. 
            \end{verse}
        \end{song}
        
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}


This is not an answer
Trying the example given in section 8.1. A First Example of the manual give me the error
./test3.tex:19: LaTeX Error: Variable \l__leadsheets_songs_height_prop undefined.

Maybe you should report a bug.
Example tested (taken from p. 14 of the documentation):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}
\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title={Mary Had A Little Lamb}, music={Stevie Ray Vaughan},
    lyrics={traditional}, tags={srv,blues}}
  \begin{verse}
    Mary had a little lamb \\
    Its fleece was white as snow, yea \\
    Everywhere the child went \\
    The little lamb was sure to go, yea
  \end{verse}
  \begin{verse}
    He followed her to school one day \\
    And broke the teacher's rule \\
    What a time did they have \\
    That day at school
  \end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}

